# Heroku app takes 3 to 4 minutes to work after deploying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a rails app which when deployed to Heroku takes 3 to 4 minutes to go live even after successful deployment. During that that period it shows error as "request timeout". I have enabled preboot as mentioned here:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/preboot but still same result. I am on Heroku enterprise and still facing this issue. Please suggest what i am missing, here is the dyno and Add-ons info that i am using

[image]

Comment: If you're on an Enterprise contract you should probably open a ticket with their support team.

Comment: Can you share the log outputs during deploy and when you try to make a request?

Comment: It's maybe the asset precompilation? Try to disable it for production. Build your assets locally, add them to the project and give it a try